# Qmail with AUTH CRAM-MD5

Tags: centos, smtp, email

My Qmail install on Centos5 has CRAM-MD5 installed.

I want to use this to an authenticated SMTP relay.

Where do I specify the username and password details for QMail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the relative qmail-remote-ath patch (you can find it [here](http://tomclegg.net/qmail/qmail-remote-auth.patch))
you should add in the file /var/qmail/control/smtproutes

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx username password

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP for your SMTP relay

Comment: Every time I read "Qmail" and "patch" as a solution for "configure" then I start to shiver...

Comment: Well he is asking about functionality that does not exist in the 'vanilla' QMail. For better or worse the way QMail was lisenced you were not allowed to apply patches and then redistribute it like other OSS software. Ofcourse there existed netqmail that did this or JMS combined patch that both added tones of functionality. 
Since the original question does not specify if he was using the original or had applied patches I had to point it out for clarity

Comment: It was not intended to offense you. My intention was to offense Qmail. I don't like Qmail (and sendmail).

Comment: Was not offended at all. Sorry if my response sounded as if I was. But in general I find that people don't really know much about QMail and was trying to clarify some things. Personally I love QMail but I agree on Sendmail ;-)

Comment: mailq, I agree :-) thanks guys, I'm no stranger to Linux, but maintaining patched versions of programs on this server is not something I'm wanting to do. I think I'll go with a different solution.  I haven't patched it incidentally, just vanilla Centos5 packages, but when I EHLO it reports CRAM-MD5 so I figured there must be a way to configure it.

Comment: CentOS or RHEL for that matter does not include Qmail packages. 
Where did you install it from? It may already include the relevant patches.